# Missing answers on Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, responses

In my account, I can see that there are two responses to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran)

[responses http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1007507/scratch/responses.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1007507/scratch/responses.jpg)

but when I click to the question page, there is only one answer. Where has Robert Harvey's answer gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been deleted.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks.

Comment: It should be removed from the most recent responses list!

Answer (score 2):

Get 9600 more rep and you'll see that it's still there.